# Woocomerce add to cart isn't working unless I switch the product to draft and then to published

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a weird bug with this website https://dib.mx. The website is working perfectly fine and all products can be added to cart however, a lot of users can't add to cart nothing unless I switch the product to draft and then to published.

I have disabled all plugins and the issue stays the same.